# figsize ignored when num = 1 for plt.figure()?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I wrote a function using matplotlib that takes an integer, instantiates a figure object with 'num' and 'figsize' parameters, and returns a list of AxesSubplot objects. However, it seems as though figsize is ignored whenever I pass `figNum = 1` to `subplotGen()`. `print(plt.gcf())` returns 'Figure(640x480)' instead of 'Figure(1280x1600)', and I'm not sure why.

My code:
'''

```
def subplotGen(figNum = None):
    gridsize = (4,2)
    axList = []
    if figNum is None:
        fig = plt.figure(num = 0, figsize = (16,20))
    else:
        fig = plt.figure(num = figNum, figsize = (16,20))
    print(fig)
    print(plt.gcf().number)
    axList.append(plt.subplot2grid(gridsize, (0, 0), colspan=2, rowspan=2)) #axisBASE
    axList.append(plt.subplot2grid(gridsize, (2, 0))) #axis b1
    axList.append(plt.subplot2grid(gridsize, (2, 1))) #axis b2
    axList.append(plt.subplot2grid(gridsize, (3, 0))) #axis b3
    axList.append(plt.subplot2grid(gridsize, (3, 1))) #axis b4
    fig.tight_layout(pad = 5.0, w_pad=5.0, h_pad=5.0)
    return axList
```

'''

I call this function before calling plt.plot on each axes in my axes list.

Thanks for reading, appreciate your help.

Comment: I believe `plt.figure()` ignores `figsize` if the figure already exists. I believe there is a function to update the size after it is created, but you can also just close the figure first (manually or programmatically).

Comment: I had a similar thought. But I haven't created an instance of figure 1 explicitly. Also, if I call 'plt.close('all')' just before calling 'subplotGen()', 'figsize' still appears to be ignored :/.